# MySQL denies access with correct credentials (Zabbix 4.0)

Tags: mysql, access-denied

I've installed Zabbix 4.0 on Apache2 with a MySQL database. I have created a user called `zabbix` with a password `zabbix`, and followed the instructions [here](https://www.zabbix.com/download?zabbix=4.4&os_distribution=ubuntu&os_version=18.04_bionic&db=mysql&ws=apache).

I can log into MySql via the CLI as user `zabbix` and write to the tables in the `zabbix` database - which means, my credentials are good.

My Zabbix configuration file looks like this:

```
<?php
// Zabbix GUI configuration file.
global $DB;

$DB['TYPE']       = 'MYSQL';
$DB['SERVER']     = 'localhost';
$DB['PORT']       = '3306';
$DB['DATABASE']   = 'zabbix';
$DB['USER']       = 'zabbix';
$DB['PASSWORD']   = 'zabbix';

// Schema name. Used for IBM DB2 and PostgresSQL.
$DB['SCHEMA'] = '';

$ZBX_SERVER       = '192.168.0.100';
$ZBX_SERVER_PORT  = '10051';
$ZBX_SERVER_NAME  = 'Test';

$IMAGE_FORMAT_DEFAULT = IMAGE_FORMAT_PNG;
```

The `zabbix_server.log` shows

```
1296:20200214:070924.785 database is down: reconnecting in 10 seconds
1296:20200214:070934.786 [Z3001] connection to database 'zabbix' failed: [1045] Access denied for user 'zabbix'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`
```

which would indicate the permissions are wrong.

The `error.log` in MySQL shows the same:

```
2020-02-14T07:10:14.791188Z 13 [Note] Access denied for user 'zabbix'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

**I have tried:**

- Changing the password
- Created a new user and granted it all privileges
- Checked for the anonymous ' ' user (it's not there)
- Changing the port (`0` is the default, tried changing the MySql port to 3000, 3500, 3306)
- Got rid of the `127.0.1.1` entry in my `/etc/hosts`
- Changed the `$DB['SERVER']` to `127.0.0.1` and `192.168.0.100`
- Reinstalled everything from scratch, including Ubuntu and LAMP - and I got to the exact same error.

What else could it be? It's a plain error message that the credentials are wrong. It's just that they are *not* wrong.

**Versions:**

`mysql -V` shows `Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.29, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

`zabbix_server --version` shows `zabbix_server (Zabbix) 4.0.17
Revision a528a0a4bc 28 January 2020, compilation time: Jan 30 2020 10:22:22`

Running on **Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS**

**EDIT**

```
mysql> show grants for 'zabbix'@'localhost';
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for zabbix@localhost                                |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'zabbix'@'localhost'                 |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `zabbix`.* TO 'zabbix'@'localhost' |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: did you try to access mysql from the terminal using the `Zabbix` user? what is the output if you try to `use` the database you created?

Comment: Did you grant privileges on correct host? GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON zabbix.* TO 'zabbix'@'localhost';

Comment: Yes, I can access the mysql console with the `zabbix` user and create tables and records in the zabbix database. I definitely have full access to that database from the console. I have granted permissions to `'zabbix'@'localhost'`

Comment: This may sound silly but it happened to me once. Try changing 
$ZBX_SERVER       = '192.168.0.100'; 
to 
$ZBX_SERVER       = 'localhost';

if that don't work, try using double quotes for all values

Comment: @mw509, thank you. It didn't make a difference. I did both, changed the server to `localhost` and enclosed everything in double quotation marks. I still have the same error

Comment: Errors as these annoy me. I just posted something as an answer. its longer. see if that helps. We will fix this BUG!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Truth is I never used Zabbix but I checked a few solutions online and I see the most common possibility considering all the things you tried already, would be that during setup you entered the wrong version number.

At the point for creating the credentials, ensure you have the correct version of the zabbix-server

```
zcat /usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql-3.4.4/create.sql.gz | mysql zabbix -uzabbix -p
```

here is a link that might help.
https://www.zabbix.com/forum/zabbix-help/52154-zabbix-cannot-connect-to-the-database?t=59755

https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-13057

I am not the one with the problem but I feel so much on edge. I hate these kind of errors. They are frustrating.

Comment: The `zcat` I ran was `zcat /usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql*/create.sql.gz | mysql -uzabbix -p zabbix`. In this version of Zabbix, there is no version in the folder name.

Comment: Did you try this yet?

1. edit /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf , find DBPassword=<password> entry, replace <password > with password you specified when creating zabbix user

2. Enable and start zabbix-server and agent

Comment: Yes. You need to put the password in quotation marks, but with or without I get the `access denied` error

Comment: Check this out. https://github.com/intellitrend/zabbixapi-php

I don't know if it will be helpful but...

Comment: It's nice, but won't help me with this. But once I get to the bottom of this bug, it will help

Comment: Yes, used Postgres instead

Comment: I promise you I saw it and overlooked it. Am glad this is solved!

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a year old, but just to help anyone else who is getting these issues on CentOS 8...

To enable your zabbix server to connect to a remote MariaDB instance.

```
setsebool -P zabbix_can_network=1
```

To allow the Web Front End to see the database:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
```

I know the last one is a bit of a sledgehammer, but it's only on my homelab and not exposed to the internet.

Hopefully it will save someone else half a day of frustration